# Magento JS Framework

Tags: magento-enterprise, javascript, magento-community, jquery

Does Magento use any JS frame work such as Node.JS? if not is it possible for us to include? We would like to know bottom of this before we proceed on Magento. I did few research about it but couldn't find a black and white answer. Therefore it would be great full if I got a direct answers. I already contact the magento community 2 days ago but they did not replied me yet.

Comment: magento does not  include any js framework in it platform defaultly

Comment: so is it using normal JQuery/Javascript for the front-end?

Answer (score 2):

Magento uses prototype.js/scriptaculous as a base for most of its javascript. It was released in 2007, at that time the options for frontend js frameworks were pretty limited. A lot of third party extensions will also add jquery.

Comment: yes. it is true